# How do I normalize this feature, I've tried almost everything

Tags: scikit-learn, data-preprocessing, scipy, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to normalize this skewed data as part of data preprocessing, but it doesn't normalize no matter which transformation I use to the point it's making me crazy :') .

The methods which I've used with their respective skew scores (top is without transformation):

Wage skew: 7.30956424189345

Wage skew when log transformed: 0.7814739131576722

Wage skew when box-cox transformed: 0.15976910824179216

Wage skew when Yeo-Johnson transformed: 0.15988186520016714

Wage skew when quantile transformed: -0.1658528258221841

Wage skew when squareroot transformed: 2.7150956859094366

Wage skew when cuberoot transformed: 1.8614016553408317

Screenshots of histograms: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxFEl.jpg

Does anybody know if there's a method I haven't tried? Or do I need to use a combination of certain methods?

Please help this noob out. Thanks in advance

```
# Distribution of skewed features
skewed_features = ['Value', 'Wage', 'Weight']
wage_features = ['Wage']
skewed_df = df[skewed_features]
log_df = np.log(skewed_df.astype(float))

# Yeo-Johnson transforming skewed features
yj_transformer = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson')
yj_transformer.fit(skewed_df)
yj_transformed = yj_transformer.fit_transform(skewed_df)
yj_df = pd.DataFrame(yj_transformed, columns = skewed_df.columns)

# Quantile transforming skewed features
q_transformer = QuantileTransformer()
q_transformer.fit(skewed_df)
q_transformed = q_transformer.fit_transform(skewed_df)
q_df = pd.DataFrame(q_transformed, columns = skewed_df.columns)

for feature in wage_features:
    #Showing skewed feature
    plt.hist(df[feature])
    plt.xlabel(feature)
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew: " + str(df[feature].skew()))
    #Showing aforementioned feature log transformed
    plt.hist(log_df[feature])
    plt.xlabel('log_'+feature)
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew when log transformed: " + str(skew(log_df[feature])))
    #Showing aforementioned feature box-cox transformed
    boxcox_data, boxcox_lambda = boxcox(df[feature].astype(float))
    plt.hist(boxcox_data)
    plt.xlabel('box-cox_' + feature + ' lambda=' + str(boxcox_lambda))
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew when box-cox transformed: " + str(skew(boxcox_data)))
    #Showing aforementioned feature Yeo-Johnson transformed
    plt.hist(yj_df[feature])
    plt.xlabel('Yeo-Johnson_'+feature)
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew when Yeo-Johnson transformed: " + str(skew(yj_df[feature])))
    #Showing aforementioned feature quantile transformed
    plt.hist(q_df[feature])
    plt.xlabel('Quantile_'+feature)
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew when quantile transformed: " + str(skew(q_df[feature])))
    #Showing aforementioned feature squareroot transformed
    sqrt_feature = np.sqrt(skewed_df[feature].astype(float))
    plt.hist(sqrt_feature)
    plt.xlabel('Squareroot_'+feature)
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew when squareroot transformed: " + str(skew(sqrt_feature)))
    #Showing aforementioned feature cuberoot transformed
    cbrt_feature = np.cbrt(skewed_df[feature].astype(float))
    plt.hist(cbrt_feature)
    plt.xlabel('Cuberoot_'+feature)
    plt.ylabel('frequency')
    plt.show()
    print(feature + " skew when cuberoot transformed: " + str(skew(cbrt_feature)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you want to transform this distribution to be normal?

Comment: Inverse normal scores transformation usually works to transform a vector of values to a near-normal distribution.  It's possible this is similar to Scikit-Learn's quantile transformation.

Comment: @Dave It's for a study assignment, the assignment doc said I have to normalize skewed distributions

Comment: Seeking a transformation often (not always, but often) involves a misunderstanding of what is assumed to be normal. Why does the study assignment want a normal distribution?

Comment: @Dave Because our lecturer told us that machine learning algorithms usually perform best when data is gaussian-distributed

Comment: I do not agree with that stance. There are features (e.g., categorical) that cannot be transformed into Gaussian features in any sensible way.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed I've been trying too hard. My teammate also told me I'm basically done. Thank you so much for your time & efforts @Dave :)

Comment: Based on the histograms, it also looks like applying a log transformation to a log transformation might work as well.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Unfortunately didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

I extracted the data approximately from the histograms, added some random variation in the data, and then applied Elfving inverse normal scores transformation. This worked well.

But I don't know if this would work as well on the actual original data.

R code for this is below.  You can run it at the following site, without installing software, but it takes a minute, since it's a relative large data set. [rdrr.io/snippets/](https://rdrr.io/snippets/).

Plots follow.

The log(log()) transformation didn't work as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]